# calculate Fourier expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let   $f(θ) = e^{bθ},\quad\ θ\in[−π, π]$ ,

Calculate Fourier expansion and then demostrate from this result the following expression:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{b^2+n^2} = \frac \pi {2b\sinh b\pi} - \frac 1 {2b^2}. $$

[my attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2fd0.jpg)

[coefficient expressions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlkMS.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Did you already begin to evaluate the cosine/sine coefficients (in case you want real Fourier series), or the complex coefficients?

Comment: I only know that there are formulas for the coefficients, I have been provided with this example as it is "easy" to understand and to learn with, but I can't  manage.

Comment: Well, at least write down those formulas. These are given as integrals...try to solve some of them...show some effort.

Comment: I've tried to solve it, although I don't know if I have done the expansion correctly. Then, I haven't been able to demostrate the expression in the statement.

Comment: Write down what you've done...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$c_n=\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{b\theta}e^{-in\theta}d\theta=\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{(b-in)\theta}d\theta=\ldots\text{(fill in details...)}$$

$$=\ldots=$$

$$=\frac1{\pi(b-in)}\left(e^{b\pi}(-1)^n-e^{-b\pi}(-1)^n\right)=\frac{2(-1)^n}{\pi(b-in)}\sinh b\pi$$

and from here that the desired Fourier series is (fill in details)

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{2(b+in)}{\pi(b^2+n^2)}\,\sinh(b\pi)\,\, e^{in\theta}$$

and this series equals $\;e^{b\theta}\;$ at any point of continuity, and it is its arithmetic mean at the function's jump discontinuities...

For example, with $\;\theta=0\;$ we get

$$e^0=1=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{2(b+in)}{\pi(b^2+n^2)}\,\sinh(b\pi)\,\, =\frac2\pi\sin h(b\pi)\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{b+in}{b^2+n^2}$$

...and now end the exercise.

Comment: Thanks! I put my attempt to a solution on the edited first message (I should have put it after your penultimate comment), but this way is way easier. For the last step, do I have to separate the sum in two sums so that the result of (b+in) is that of the statement?

Comment: @PepeDiaz That's right, but it is pretty clear the sum on the imaginary part vanishes, so you only get the sum of the real part.